# HTML non SGML character number 3

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

Currently I based a website into HTMl, but I'm getting some errors that I've never had before. It's about non SGML character number 3. But the problem is it shows that my whitespace is an error.. how am I able to fix this?

Url: http://htmlhelp.com/cgi-bin/validate.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Frasure.nl%2Fvca%2F&warnings=yes&input=yes

I hope someone can clearify this problem for me and has a solution for it!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You really should move on from XHTML *transitional* to HTML 5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a `0x03` control character right before `<br/>`. Looking at the source with a hex editor, you'll see:

```
0000260: 6464 6c65 4c65 6674 223e 0a09 0909 0909  ddleLeft">......
0000270: 0956 4341 2062 6173 6973 033c 6272 2f3e  .VCA basis.<br/>
0000280: 5643 4120 564f 4c0a 0909 0909 093c 2f64  VCA VOL......</d
```

Notice the `03` right before `3c` ("`<`"), after `62 61 73 69 73` ("`basis`").

Comment: That's clear, but why am I getting this in HTMl 5 doctype too? http://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Frasure.nl%2Fvca

Comment: @Mittchel, apparently you also have some [U+0003](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm) characters inside the document... Updated answer.

Comment: Cool thanks, but how am I able to fix this cause I'm not able to see anything in my document haha :P Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: @Mittchel, it's not a visible character... You could try removing that line altogether and rewriting it.

Comment: @Mittchel, it's likely from the source from where you got that text. You probably copied it along with some extra invisible characters (maybe a Word document or a PDF?), then pasted it inside the HTML document with the invisible characters and everything.

Comment: Yep it's clear text.. and I copied straight from a PSD file. So that could be it haha.. thanks for the explanation. Rep this guy!